# SpringFramewok HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, codificação-de-caracteres, http-request

Venho tentando encontrar soluções para este erro e não encontro.

**Erro:**

> 2018-07-24 16:44:50.541  WARN 25695 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

**Algoritmo em tscript que é chamado após um clique em botão:**

```
uploadKeySize(e) {
    let keySize = parseInt(e.target.value);
    console.log(keySize);
    this.fileService.sendInfoToGenKey(keySize).toPromise()
        .then(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
  }
```

**método do file service que é chamado e que faz a comunicação com o back:**

```
sendInfoToGenKey(sizeKey: number) {
        return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/operation/request-RSA-keys', sizeKey);
    }
```

**Código:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-RSA-keys", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public static KeyPair generateRSAKeys(@RequestBody int sizeKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    System.out.println(sizeKey);
    return KeyGenerator.generateKey("RSA", sizeKey);
}
```

Comment: Consegue colocar o request que está sendo enviado pelo client também? Isso pode ajudar a identificar o problema.

Comment: Só um detalhe que não é o que você está perguntando, mas que tem a ver com o seu código é que o `NoSuchAlgorithmException` nunca será lançado pelo método. Assim sendo, recomendo envolver a chamada do `generateKey` em um bloco `try` e no `catch` do `NoSuchAlgorithmException` lançar um `AssertionError`.

Comment: Espere um pouco, que classe `KeyGenerator` é essa? Certamente não é [`javax.crypto.KeyGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html).

Comment: Você consegue pegar um stacktrace do seu erro? Acho que você precisará postar mais sobre o seu código para que a origem do problema e a possível solução possam ser apontados.

Comment: A classe KeyGenerator é uma que criei. Nela é só uma "interface" que é chamada quando chamo o método do back. Nela eu uso o KeyPairGenerator

Comment: Por padrão, o Spring possui alguns HttpMessageConverter(s) pre-habiltados que fazem a conversão de um request body pra objetos Java. Se não me engano, a conversão de um POST text/plain pra int não está habilitado. Você tem algumas opções: 1 - Trabalhar com application/json. 2 - Receber uma String sizeKey e converter pra int. 3 - Registrar um HttpMessageConverter pra efetuar a conversão de um POST plain/text pra int. Da uma olhada [aqui](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) e [aqui](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-message-body.html)

Comment: @TomMelo disse tudo, vc tem que simplificar a sua resposta