# No serializer found for class sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier

Tags: java, spring

Estou com o seguinte problema:

**Erro:**

> ```
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.security.KeyPair["public"]->sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl["algorithmId"]->sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId["oid"])
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:312) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>     at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:272) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
> ```

**Código:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/operation")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class SecurityOperationsRest {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityOperations securityOperations;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hash", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public static String hash256Base64(@RequestBody String clearText) {
        return SecurityOperations.hash256Base64(clearText);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/request-RSA-keys", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public static KeyPair generateRSAKeys(@RequestBody String sizeKey) {
        return SecurityOperations.generateRSAKeys(Integer.parseInt(sizeKey));
    }

}
```

**Erro:**

> PUT http://localhost:8080/operation/request-RSA-keys 500 ()
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 500 OK for
>   URL: http://localhost:8080/operation/request-RSA-keys

Comment: Isso é relacionado à sua [**pergunta anterior**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317438/132), né?

Comment: Você quer converter um `java.security.KeyPair` em JSON usando o Jackson?

Comment: Isso @VictorStafusa

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Leia [**isso**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos inventar uma implementação funcional para seu método `generateRSA`:

```
public class SecurityOperations {
    public static KeyPair generateRSAKeys(int keySize) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize);
            return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

O objeto `KeyPair` do Java não pode ser serializado como JSON pelo Jackson, então precisamos montar um outro objeto para fazer isso. Dando uma olhada no que há dentro do objeto [`KeyPair`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html) de acordo com os javadocs, considerando que a implementação de [`PublicKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html) será uma [`RSAPublicKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) e a de [`PrivateKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/PrivateKey.html)  será uma [`RSAPrivateCrtKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html), os métodos [`getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()) são responsáveis por transformar a chave em um array de bytes. Outros métodos também podem ser vistos tal como exemplificado a seguir:

```
public static void mostrar(KeyPair k) {
    Base64.Encoder b64e = Base64.getEncoder();
    RSAPublicKey pu = (RSAPublicKey) k.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateCrtKey pr = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) k.getPrivate();
    System.out.println("public algorithm: " + pu.getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("public encoded: " + Arrays.toString(pu.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("public encoded b64: " + new String(b64e.encode(pu.getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("public format: " + pu.getFormat());
    System.out.println("public modulus: " + pu.getModulus());
    System.out.println("public exponent: " + pu.getPublicExponent());
    System.out.println("private algorithm: " + pr.getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("private encoded: " + Arrays.toString(pr.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("private encoded b64: " + new String(b64e.encode(pr.getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("private format: " + pr.getFormat());
    System.out.println("private modulus: " + pr.getModulus());
    System.out.println("private public exponent: " + pr.getPublicExponent());
    System.out.println("private exponent: " + pr.getPrivateExponent());
    System.out.println("private prime P: " + pr.getPrimeP());
    System.out.println("private prime Q: " + pr.getPrimeQ());
    System.out.println("private prime exponent P: " + pr.getPrimeExponentP());
    System.out.println("private prime exponent Q: " + pr.getPrimeExponentQ());
    System.out.println("private CRT coefficient: " + pr.getCrtCoefficient());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyPair kp = SecurityOperations.generateRSAKeys(2048);
    mostrar(kp);
}
```

Eis a saída produzida (provavelmente vai variar, vez que as chaves são geradas aleatoriamente):

```
public algorithm: RSA
public encoded: [48, -126, 1, 34, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, -126, 1, 15, 0, 48, -126, 1, 10, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -105, 64, -21, -13, 48, -41, 15, -101, 95, 88, -51, -98, 3, 87, 39, 69, 107, 34, -112, -23, 95, -115, 77, 51, -44, -76, 127, -79, -31, 54, -44, -17, -80, -41, 26, -111, 81, -110, -92, 104, -37, 18, -39, 77, -50, 112, -93, -62, -78, 20, 8, 53, 32, -127, -7, -34, -25, 47, -118, 126, -61, -84, -96, 113, -107, 125, -105, 117, 55, -128, -37, 119, 109, 83, 36, 14, 124, -118, 125, 127, 124, 74, 6, 23, 26, 101, 44, -42, -103, -115, -41, 30, -86, 124, 72, 3, -83, -93, -61, -97, 17, 2, -100, -100, 55, -56, 6, 27, 105, 50, -106, 34, 11, -124, -69, -56, 46, 103, -13, 92, -103, -81, -63, 118, -63, 85, -107, 122, -55, 7, 28, -13, 115, 115, 78, 32, 5, 27, -28, -101, -16, 56, -47, 55, -8, 110, 104, 75, -100, -54, 42, -28, -128, 48, -52, 80, -97, -20, -84, -53, -126, -54, 110, -79, 113, 107, -71, 42, -71, -123, 27, 12, 26, -80, 102, 124, 64, 100, -21, -44, 28, 38, 39, 89, -52, 37, 46, 118, 19, 43, 42, -85, 120, -128, -113, -54, -22, 7, 55, -100, 112, -105, 84, -56, 88, -67, -72, -124, 105, -12, 112, 76, -112, -117, -111, -90, 126, -92, 59, -6, 116, -111, 109, 73, 118, 86, -16, -61, 119, 79, -38, 97, -16, -125, -81, 67, 42, 71, 0, 111, 45, 126, -123, 82, 59, -14, -27, 35, 107, -60, 60, 47, -48, -117, -111, -35, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
public encoded b64: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl0Dr8zDXD5tfWM2eA1cnRWsikOlfjU0z1LR/seE21O+w1xqRUZKkaNsS2U3OcKPCshQINSCB+d7nL4p+w6ygcZV9l3U3gNt3bVMkDnyKfX98SgYXGmUs1pmN1x6qfEgDraPDnxECnJw3yAYbaTKWIguEu8guZ/Ncma/BdsFVlXrJBxzzc3NOIAUb5JvwONE3+G5oS5zKKuSAMMxQn+ysy4LKbrFxa7kquYUbDBqwZnxAZOvUHCYnWcwlLnYTKyqreICPyuoHN5xwl1TIWL24hGn0cEyQi5GmfqQ7+nSRbUl2VvDDd0/aYfCDr0MqRwBvLX6FUjvy5SNrxDwv0IuR3QIDAQAB
public format: X.509
public modulus: 19093998123240252180582981692150144828830602901797443454519587825183993619017054481175293838417376823489124484356227417822926340061836799578918821120350733238600269437402822692122921155415438777156119457909139578459186074935896528785696831008218655198210881466235062369049263837293988599114822903617658097938619169676862043291486270178383148786736245093111668396013934934678252254734808521433323949822262053901441665722210528585024303410822707682321439608316841995757619747917646039475558643433789028709687382507498557032525353420421280426426441628371937858875882959460301371729699031347236517313006952994100973638109
public exponent: 65537
private algorithm: RSA
private encoded: [48, -126, 4, -68, 2, 1, 0, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 4, -126, 4, -90, 48, -126, 4, -94, 2, 1, 0, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -105, 64, -21, -13, 48, -41, 15, -101, 95, 88, -51, -98, 3, 87, 39, 69, 107, 34, -112, -23, 95, -115, 77, 51, -44, -76, 127, -79, -31, 54, -44, -17, -80, -41, 26, -111, 81, -110, -92, 104, -37, 18, -39, 77, -50, 112, -93, -62, -78, 20, 8, 53, 32, -127, -7, -34, -25, 47, -118, 126, -61, -84, -96, 113, -107, 125, -105, 117, 55, -128, -37, 119, 109, 83, 36, 14, 124, -118, 125, 127, 124, 74, 6, 23, 26, 101, 44, -42, -103, -115, -41, 30, -86, 124, 72, 3, -83, -93, -61, -97, 17, 2, -100, -100, 55, -56, 6, 27, 105, 50, -106, 34, 11, -124, -69, -56, 46, 103, -13, 92, -103, -81, -63, 118, -63, 85, -107, 122, -55, 7, 28, -13, 115, 115, 78, 32, 5, 27, -28, -101, -16, 56, -47, 55, -8, 110, 104, 75, -100, -54, 42, -28, -128, 48, -52, 80, -97, -20, -84, -53, -126, -54, 110, -79, 113, 107, -71, 42, -71, -123, 27, 12, 26, -80, 102, 124, 64, 100, -21, -44, 28, 38, 39, 89, -52, 37, 46, 118, 19, 43, 42, -85, 120, -128, -113, -54, -22, 7, 55, -100, 112, -105, 84, -56, 88, -67, -72, -124, 105, -12, 112, 76, -112, -117, -111, -90, 126, -92, 59, -6, 116, -111, 109, 73, 118, 86, -16, -61, 119, 79, -38, 97, -16, -125, -81, 67, 42, 71, 0, 111, 45, 126, -123, 82, 59, -14, -27, 35, 107, -60, 60, 47, -48, -117, -111, -35, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, -126, 1, 0, 10, -8, -56, -92, -31, 124, 24, 67, -69, 12, -28, 13, 124, 76, -116, 42, -70, -12, -52, -14, 64, -34, 45, 37, 127, 94, -128, -116, -44, -69, 119, -126, -45, -97, 38, -20, 55, -80, -99, -128, -123, -77, -66, 83, -88, -113, -1, 49, 22, 93, -31, -94, -120, -13, 36, -65, 8, -94, 40, 55, -67, -43, -3, -27, 127, 100, -106, -30, 7, -34, -81, 12, -32, -65, 81, 52, 67, -48, 127, -2, 9, 116, 13, 49, 11, -41, 31, 3, -118, 44, 1, -40, -43, -95, 34, 80, 49, -2, 89, 40, 102, -63, 123, -66, -47, 69, 15, 60, 89, -53, 51, -100, -48, -99, 22, 74, 21, 35, -79, 65, -100, 92, 101, 122, 73, -41, -3, 121, -57, -69, -80, -7, 78, -110, 14, -107, -87, -2, -117, -24, -95, -12, -97, -100, 37, 38, 46, -19, 90, -88, 109, 114, 15, -43, -47, -110, -49, 63, -76, 52, 43, -77, -53, 33, -79, 62, 39, -122, -56, 98, -119, -80, 125, -81, -51, -78, -15, 126, -1, -99, 77, 108, -52, 109, 27, 8, -44, 25, 33, -97, 124, -71, -126, -90, -46, -36, -36, -41, 21, -19, -124, -120, 25, 26, 21, 23, -53, -39, 49, -126, 22, 34, 82, 37, 1, 27, -103, 64, -104, 123, 46, -20, 87, 2, -62, 31, 46, -41, 41, -92, 48, -16, 13, -14, 44, 88, -101, 69, 33, 48, 25, -106, -44, -12, 27, -59, -88, 60, 27, 51, -111, -16, -127, 77, -111, -71, 2, -127, -127, 0, -24, -63, 108, -119, -24, 100, 121, 53, 72, 31, -5, 118, 38, 69, -97, 61, 108, -29, 20, -29, 88, -119, -108, 116, 34, -23, 80, -40, -22, 91, 59, 8, -112, 113, 13, 4, 114, -123, 18, 70, 79, 109, -47, 96, 32, -108, 67, -59, 72, -92, 66, 20, -107, 65, 17, -126, 12, -18, -102, 115, -114, 78, 46, -68, -81, 75, -89, 43, 82, 18, -38, 55, -125, -28, 103, -124, -86, -55, -117, 89, 76, 9, 32, -52, 123, -100, -35, -126, 16, -92, -121, 29, -2, -125, 6, -106, 10, 116, 61, -19, 17, 101, -30, 89, 19, 43, 42, 100, 116, -9, -44, -13, 6, -48, -101, 119, 76, 45, -128, -71, -89, 19, 57, 53, -7, -94, 61, 47, 2, -127, -127, 0, -90, 91, -42, 68, -68, 24, 90, -51, 50, -108, 106, -36, 116, 11, -31, -77, -93, 111, -119, 16, -15, -5, 112, -128, -86, 101, -30, -101, -11, -97, 11, 61, 48, -103, -39, 36, 50, -74, 92, -121, -107, 53, 2, 54, 75, -70, -49, 25, -87, -56, 36, 102, -98, -107, 73, -35, -50, -98, 31, -106, -15, 99, -23, 118, 105, -115, 91, 4, 51, 66, 76, 33, 67, -39, 18, 105, 37, -17, -47, 91, 19, -43, -109, 28, -5, -33, -3, 60, -64, 14, 11, 118, -128, -94, -21, -35, 120, 125, 77, 93, -37, 114, -73, 20, 59, -83, 122, 70, 3, 20, -4, -28, -109, -70, 96, -104, -87, -85, -7, -106, -75, -123, -6, 118, -76, 3, 86, -77, 2, -127, -128, 8, 118, -104, 10, -65, -81, 127, -108, -57, 101, -102, 80, 38, 126, 27, -105, 49, 49, 100, -98, 11, -89, 29, 5, -56, 11, 49, -52, 97, 97, 37, -39, 94, -33, 45, 120, -2, -19, 5, -56, 22, -75, 72, -118, -75, 68, -114, -34, 74, -112, -26, 114, 55, 39, 33, -118, -40, 11, -119, 4, 48, -91, 121, 31, -107, 68, 43, -12, -16, 76, 13, 49, 61, -109, 125, -116, 30, 101, -85, -78, 120, -120, 80, 111, -1, 2, -86, 47, 67, -119, -89, -4, 24, 56, 13, 114, 65, 57, 14, -45, 98, -15, -112, 116, 106, -75, 4, 26, -103, 2, 53, -11, 12, 71, 99, -113, -57, -18, 83, -94, -20, -121, 79, 106, 62, 4, 127, 51, 2, -127, -128, 110, -74, -16, 3, 14, -85, -90, -62, -87, -58, -36, -41, -102, -29, -51, 114, 32, 115, 58, 101, 108, -90, 74, 89, 87, 14, 55, -94, 83, -11, 101, 37, 116, 18, -17, -48, -121, 111, -106, 101, 37, -120, 1, -48, -32, -43, -110, -65, 33, -97, 113, -102, 90, 48, 64, -40, -67, -119, -66, -68, 86, 42, -120, 85, -90, 41, -51, 73, 30, 84, 33, 22, -126, 113, 21, 47, -91, 111, -43, -123, 39, -50, 27, -6, 78, 38, -28, 2, 106, 78, -18, -110, 15, 74, 94, 111, 38, -95, 61, -68, 25, 48, 95, 103, -73, -49, -36, 112, 123, -36, -101, -14, 3, -33, 38, 42, 115, -63, 96, 122, 76, -108, -67, -4, 2, 17, -74, -63, 2, -127, -128, 55, -34, 14, 14, 81, -114, 43, 103, 33, 91, 26, 24, -9, 4, 80, 117, 20, -66, 124, -27, -31, 121, -88, -92, -42, 77, 25, -57, -76, 25, -37, -28, 31, 110, 46, 101, -2, 121, 9, -48, -33, -101, -53, -54, -127, 16, -75, 10, 20, -27, -68, 16, 25, -85, -26, -90, -26, 56, 112, 61, 64, -68, -120, 127, -89, -66, 21, -59, 12, -19, -49, 26, -58, -81, -70, 15, -111, -104, 58, -92, 2, 76, 119, 36, 107, 94, 52, 127, 82, -19, -17, 106, -119, -56, -113, -50, 85, 40, -79, -47, -64, 66, 9, 8, -56, 69, 57, -128, 67, -46, 82, -4, -122, 82, -116, -1, -33, 67, -35, -27, 56, -25, 64, 16, -68, 59, -65, 91]
private encoded b64: 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
private format: PKCS#8
private modulus: 19093998123240252180582981692150144828830602901797443454519587825183993619017054481175293838417376823489124484356227417822926340061836799578918821120350733238600269437402822692122921155415438777156119457909139578459186074935896528785696831008218655198210881466235062369049263837293988599114822903617658097938619169676862043291486270178383148786736245093111668396013934934678252254734808521433323949822262053901441665722210528585024303410822707682321439608316841995757619747917646039475558643433789028709687382507498557032525353420421280426426441628371937858875882959460301371729699031347236517313006952994100973638109
private public exponent: 65537
private exponent: 1385062896957202173832972137334357515849988345440667808761251209559862454259533957970418952772269243616084010538009142077455358357171859334394007592751382971700042432601629904914054155253444557221114666568504044371804791190400111354611940348399705308639311083670010627621957066733228890553303753357620071068234175206467715071430957112047097648304499050663377930133554042365863403753737570076381030070520699317037698947196347863859272622193490216279446699486953429387881067902697902595959388326081303450064822132405216055743367243667023940226146997997801295602085346286980230520369315767210190391626311296904332153273
private prime P: 163446514321073004442310556270960412203771433624655158721006609579827500850107863546845692572650063382225022074429964559294811733212783258552058786426329332982667733134837610861879996684888893357686279366658034746022149419467787909834301728035554629464902772892485459762980590312425691200796671107481328565551
private prime Q: 116821078764225937786358391100274496338962030684783660691596546694640594900960832456149362059936965037369846024219972954264378122562644595349923871054066112124223881181817170214143427412259330933217289911677576420863099026572813515624324206650665200409325298134954454748913677165300046201395480989434281940659
private prime exponent P: 5943101509484977487312908060999109850642954763378751594246894893399590071651235772649545835186613684481166785226156301704373657021927499048317074142147837107247771610850634400168760121764655581905891385488290535114069641066752194777532401817427204205484891096675051507014095041190631584166172806950699695923
private prime exponent Q: 77746435927498642026485917668333497601662693293063828749022307713710487010395771372009865810247809131786978412078342621316128541033192039165391756715964227023057948969683349803318426690466499503840659730957004030888886081801117449646314671060247087615440624432826853507615834463611804249814079052064721319617
private CRT coefficient: 39231423826464180962220915291000320841879655929334305881366464052655074878611840446781910148747551748349989044895551744049159735078739671304472930837060362338022547504311898612471588078035380996563722887816479784108365174533582035576898575410992828487201106190178397938016504118904196690718456301943464378203
```

Embora ver esse monte de informação até seja legal, o que você precisa mesmo é só dos [métodos `getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()). No entanto, você ainda precisa ser capaz de reconstruir o `KeyPair` a partir desses arrays de bytes. Para facilitar, como você pode ver no código, já estou usando Base64 para converter o `byte[]` em uma `String` que possa ser facilmente transportada no JSON.

Então, para reconstruir o `KeyPair` a partir das strings codificadas em Base64, você pode fazer isso na classe `SecurityOperations`:

```
private static final Base64.Decoder b64d = Base64.getDecoder();
private static final KeyFactory keyFactory;

static {
    try {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

private static RSAPublicKey rebuildPublicKey(String base64key) {
    try {
        byte[] b = b64d.decode(base64key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(b));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

private static RSAPrivateCrtKey rebuildPrivateKey(String base64key) {
    try {
        byte[] b = b64d.decode(base64key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

public static KeyPair rebuildKey(String base64PublicKey, String base64PrivateKey) {
    return new KeyPair(rebuildPublicKey(base64PublicKey), rebuildPrivateKey(base64PrivateKey));
}
```

Tendo então como converter a `KeyPair` em duas strings e vice-versa, usamos uma classe para agrupá-las:

```
public final class EncodedKeyPair {
    private static final Base64.Encoder b64e = Base64.getEncoder();
    private final String base64PublicKey;
    private final String base64PrivateKey;

    public EncodedKeyPair(KeyPair kp) {
        this.base64PublicKey = new String(b64e.encode(kp.getPublic().getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        this.base64PrivateKey = new String(b64e.encode(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public EncodedKeyPair(
            @JsonProperty("base64PublicKey") int base64PublicKey,
            @JsonProperty("base64PrivateKey") int base64PrivateKey)
    {
        this.base64PublicKey = base64PublicKey;
        this.base64PrivateKey = base64PrivateKey;
    }

    public KeyPair rebuild() {
        return SecurityOperations.rebuildKey(base64PublicKey, base64PrivateKey);
    }
}
```

O Jackson utiliza serialização baseada nos atributos, sem fazer uso dos getters e setters. Para a desserialização, o Jackson vai utilizar o construtor anotado com `@JsonCreator`.

Para testar isso tudo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyPair kp = SecurityOperations.generateRSAKeys(2048);
    mostrar(kp);
    System.out.println();
    mostrar(new EncodedKeyPair(kp).rebuild());
}
```

E você vai observar que as duas saídas são iguais.

[**Veja isso funcionando no Coding Ground.**](http://tpcg.io/X3TCDC)

Por fim, você faz essa altera o método `generateRSAKeys` em sua controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-RSA-keys", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public static EncodedKeyPair generateRSAKeys(@RequestBody String sizeKey) {
    return new EncodedKeyPair(SecurityOperations.generateRSAKeys(Integer.parseInt(sizeKey)));
}
```

E na sua controller, você pode apagar isso:

```
@Autowired
private SecurityOperations securityOperations;
```

O motivo é que o `SecurityOperations` não precisa ser injetado, vez que você usa os métodos estáticos dele ao invés de utilizar uma instância gerenciada pelo Spring.

Por fim, faço uma observação importante: Exportar a chave privada (que está dentro do `KeyPair`) é quase sempre uma péssima ideia. Idealmente, você não deve exportar a chave privada nunca! Apenas a chave pública deveria ser exportada.

Comment: Entendo. Eu fiz isso bem simples. A ideia é um site para gerar pares de chaves RSA. Por enquanto estou fazendo simples mesmo pra ver funcionando. Com o tempo acrescendo mais proteções de segurança. Eu acabei fazendo desta maneira, criei um novo objeto mas só com os itens que vou usar. Terei que fazer com todos mesmo. Penso que eu poderia criptografar a chave privada para que o usuário descriptografe depois.